# Why do the names of my contacts not appear when in airplane mode?

Tags: contacts, 7.0-nougat, lenovo

I have noticed something weird in my Lenovo K6 (Android 7). When I turn airplane mode on and go to my contacts, only numbers appear. Why does this happen?

Note: I have my contacts stored in the SIM card.

Comment: Might sound crazy, and I see no reason why it should be so – but the connection popping to my head by your description is: "when in airplane mode, SIM is switched off". But then, consequently, the contact list should be empty altogether – or not?

Comment: @Izzy that's what I thought too! Weird, isn't it?